# Problems to simulate download on ie

Tags: javascript

i'm doing:

```
iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
frame.src="http://localhost/file.csv";
iframe.style.display='none';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

it works fine on ff,chrome,safari but on ie always come a message about security that blocks it.

someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: You need the page to come from the same origin. Does it? I.e. is the page that hosts the script ALSO on localhost, same port, same protocol? Anyway, if you do not have plans to show the iframe, why do you append it to the body?

Comment: cuz i need to trigger the download without refresh page

Comment: That does not make me any wiser - Why append it at all. Any why not use AJAX

Comment: how can i simulate download with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use jQuery which is as simple as
$("result").load("file.csv"), then have a look here

http://plungjan.name/test/simpleajax.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function xmlhttpget(URL) {
  var xmlHttpReq = (window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xmlHttpReq.open('GET', URL, true);
  xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
      show(xmlHttpReq.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlHttpReq.send();
}
function show(str){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="xmlhttpget('file.csv')" value="Get">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```